# Random sampling in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi please the code below, throws the error below when size > 5. Would there be another random function in python 2.7 that can generate say 6 or more different samples from the initial individual, so that population will have say 6 lists appended to it. Thank you

```
import random as rand

population = []
individual = [1,2,3,4,5]
size = 5

for ind in individual:
        population.append((rand.sample(individual, size)))

print "pop", population

#output
pop =  [[1, 3, 5, 2, 4], [3, 4, 5, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 5, 3, 4, 2], [1, 5, 3, 2, 4]]
```

> ```
> #Error Message
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/AMAMIFE/Desktop/obi/tt.py", line 10, in <module>
>     population.append((rand.sample(individual, size)))
>   File "C:\Python27\x86\lib\random.py", line 321, in sample
>     raise ValueError("sample larger than population")
> ValueError: sample larger than population
> ```

Comment: How would you generate *six* different samples if the original population only contains *five* items?

Comment: What do you mean by a "sample"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you're using `sample` here doesn't seem to be correct. `random.sample(a_sequence, n)` chooses `n` objects from `a_sequence` at random. For example:

```
>>> import random
>>> my_list = range(5)
>>> random.sample(my_list, 3)
[0, 3, 2]
>>> random.sample(my_list, 3)
[4, 1, 0]
>>> random.sample(my_list, 3)
[2, 0, 4]
>>> random.sample(my_list, 3)
[4, 0, 2]
>>> random.sample(my_list, 3)
[1, 4, 3]
```

It doesn't make sense to try and sample 6 items from a list of 5 items. After you've pulled out 5 items, there is no sixth item for you to pull out.

When you say you want to sample 5 items from a list of size 5, you're just saying you want everything in a random order. If you want to get `n` of those, try using `itertools.permutations`:

```
>>> import random
>>> import itertools
>>> my_list = range(5)
>>> random.sample(list(itertools.permutations(my_list)), 5)
[(4, 2, 1, 3, 0), (3, 0, 2, 4, 1), (2, 3, 0, 4, 1), (4, 3, 0, 1, 2), (4, 0, 3, 2, 1)]
>>> random.sample(list(itertools.permutations(my_list)), 6)
[(0, 2, 1, 4, 3), (1, 2, 4, 0, 3), (1, 0, 3, 2, 4), (2, 1, 4, 3, 0), (0, 3, 2, 1, 4), (4, 2, 0, 1, 3)]
>>> random.sample(list(itertools.permutations(my_list)), 7)
[(4, 3, 1, 2, 0), (3, 0, 1, 2, 4), (2, 0, 1, 3, 4), (4, 2, 3, 1, 0), (0, 4, 1, 3, 2), (3, 0, 2, 1, 4), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the wrong variable; you should be changing the `for` loop, not the argument to `sample`:

```
size = len(individual)
pop_size = 6
for _ in range(pop_size):
    population.append(rand.sample(individual, size))
```

Note that `pop_size` is the number of sub-lists to add to `population`, whereas `size` is the length of `individual`. You could also consider using:

```
for _ in range(pop_size):
    rand.shuffle(individual)
    population.append(individual[:])
```

i.e. on each iteration randomly shuffle `individual` and append a copy of it to `population`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension:

```
from random import choice
pop = [[choice(individual) for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(size)]
```

This will work as long as `individual` isn't an empty sequence.

NOTE: I use the `size` variable for both the size of each sub list and the number of sub lists . If you want 5 lists of 10 values you would have to adjust that accordingly.

EDIT: shortened some variable names ot make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import random as rand
individual = 5
population = []
size = 5

for ind in individual:
        population.append((rand.sample(xrange(individual), size)))

print "pop", population
```

Comment: That's not going to fix the problem that's happening when size is larger than the number of individuals

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain some of the contents. If you do explain this (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner actually learns something!

Comment: With the New version 2.3. of python, random.sample(population, k) Returns a new list containing elements from the population while leaving the original population unchanged. The resulting list is in selection order so that all sub-slices will also be valid random samples. This allows raffle winners (the sample) to be partitioned into grand prize and second place winners (the subslices).

Members of the population need not be hashable or unique. If the population contains repeats, then each occurrence is a possible selection in the sample.

Comment: To choose a sample from a range of integers, use an xrange() object as an argument. This is especially fast and space efficient for sampling from a large population: sample(xrange(10000000), 60).